# Ubuntu 18.04 - How to add Grayscale to the printer options

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, hp, system-settings

I've been looking for an answer online but I could not find one that would solve my problem.

I cannot print in black and white (or "grayscale" apparently) as there is no option in my settings. If I go into any program (OpenOffice, gedit, etc. etc.) and click on the "print" button and then go to the "colour" tab it says (translated from Italian): [printer profile: profile not specified].

Then I go to Settings --> Devices --> Printers --> Additional printer options I still cannot find what I need. I want to be able to print ***both in colours and b/w***.

The device model is HP Envy 4500 series, just in case.

I wonder why this is not a default option...

Anyway, thank you in advance for all the answers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I also have an HP Envy 4500 series. It is on
the network and uses driverless printing. With
cups 2.2.10 `lpoptions -p envy4500 -l`shows

> ColorModel/Output Mode: *RGB

With cups 2.3.3 the same command gives

> ColorModel/Output Mode: *RGB Gray Gray16 DeviceGray DeviceRGB AdobeRGB

Upgrading to Ubuntu 21.4 would appear to be a solution.